# Dask dataframe running out of memory while converting it to pandas after selecting subset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask

So I have a parquet file with `160M` records and `240` columns. So I'm using dask to load it in python using EMR CLuster `m5.12xlarge`.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_parquet(file)
```

Now I want value count and normalized value count of one of the column:

```
count = df.a.value_counts()
percent = df.a.value_counts(normalize = True)
a_count = dd.concat([count,percent], axis=1, keys=['counts', '%'])
```

Out:

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
    counts  %
npartitions=1       
    int64   float64
    ...     ...
Dask Name: concat, 489 tasks
```

Note here that I have total `1 npartitions` and `489 task`.

Now I'm trying to convert it into pandas df. Which is only taking few secs to execute and using around `1.5 GB` of memory.

```
a_count = a_count.compute()
```

Now from one of the column I want all records with null values and then do the same as I did earlier, value count.

```
empty_b = df[df['b'].isna()]

count = empty_b.a.value_counts()
percent = empty_b.a.value_counts(normalize = True)
empty_b = dd.concat([count,percent], axis=1, keys=['counts', '%'])
empty_b
```

Out:

```
Dask DataFrame Structure:
    counts  %
npartitions=1       
    int64   float64
    ...     ...
Dask Name: concat, 828 tasks
```

Which has a total `1 npartition` and `828 task`.

Now I'm trying to convert this into pandas dataframe by computing and it's taking lot of time and running out of memory after utilizing `170 GB`.

```
empty_b  = empty_b.compute()
```

Can someone explain what's going wrong here, I'm doing the same thing and that also on subset of bigger one, but still my notebook is running out of memory and not able to execute.

Comment: @MRocklin can you please look into it

Comment: @mdurant can you please check this out

Answer (score 0):

> I have a parquet file with 160M records and 240 columns

It's probably best to split up this data into multiple Parquet files

> I'm using dask to load it in python using EMR CLuster m5.12xlarge

This instance type has 48 CPUs.  Is this a multi node instance or a single node?

> Note here that I have total 1 npartitions and 489 task.

You're probably running all these computations on a single core.  Try repartitioning the DataFrame into 48 partitions at least, so you can leverage parallelism on your powerful machine.

> Now I'm trying to convert this into pandas dataframe

You generally don't want to convert Dask DataFrames to Pandas DataFrames, unless you've significantly reduced the number of rows of data.  You lose all the benefits that the parallelism of Dask can provide once converting to Pandas.

In this example, it seems like you're reading a single Parquet file into a Dask DataFrame with one partition and then converting it back to Pandas.  You might want to consider breaking up the Dask DataFrame into multiple partitions (and running computations via Dask) or just reading the file directly into a Pandas DataFrame.